# "interaction" vs. "interacting" vs "to interact"?

Tags: grammar, phrases, expressions

> Interaction and cooperation with the young researchers will help us gain a more comprehensive understanding of our own fields.

What is the difference or which is correct here to use "interaction", "interacting" or "to interact"? Are they the same? And the same question also applies to "cooperation".

Comment: The same question can be asked about almost any verb in the English language...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interacting is present tense for Interact

Interaction "is the situation or occurrence in which two or more objects or events act upon one another to produce a new effect; the effect resulting from such a situation or occurrence. "